# external hard drive not responding

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, partition-recovery

I made a big mistake by unplugging the external harddrive (2TB, western digital) while it was still copying files. I just forgot it was copying files.

Now the hard disk won't respond. When I plug it in, the light is just blinking, but no mounted directory appears (I am using Mac OS).

Disk Utility does not help either... Repair does not work, nothing, even after rebooting the machine (I thought maybe the devices were still busy).

Is the hard disk really gone? I find it surprising that just unplugging it by mistake completely ruins the hard disk, instead of just trashing a few files that were being written.

Comment: I'll reference you o this earlier question which is quite similar http://superuser.com/questions/481196/cannot-access-disk-partition-table-broken/481236#481236

Comment: Plug it in and leave it for a couple of hours.  It may be doing some sort of internal recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have corrupted the partition table, happens all to often and I'll admit, I've done it before to. Using software like gparted should fix your problem although you could lose the data on the drive. I have left a comment with a reference to a question with similar problem but with windows.

Comment: "Disk Utility does not help either... Repair does not work" does it make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, I have ran into this problem before, and trust me software such as a Gparted live disc will solve the problem, click the link I provided and read the info.

Comment: Anyway, any attempts to get it working are acceptable in such a situation)

Comment: So did this fix your problem, if so feel free to upvote or mark as the answer.