# Rescue partition from HDD with broken partition table

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, partition-recovery

### Problem

My external (USB) hard disk isn't detected correctly by the computer any longer. I want to recover its second veracrypted primary partition `/dev/sdb2`. I know exactly it's size and it's position on the HDD.

Moreover, I only have just enough space on my SSD to store that partition, but I don't have anywhere to store the rest of the HDD.

### Causes

These events happened in the following order

1. The HDD fell on the ground, but still worked afterwards. But there might be a hardware issue at stake.
2. Created a 100GB ExFAT partition as `/dev/sdb4` (My last permitted primary partition)
3. Tried to format `/dev/sdb4` to make it ext4 with GParted. GParted had erased the previous partition ok, but it was stuck doing some writing. It was taking much longer than expected, so I tried to cancel it, but GParted just continued "working on it". I let it run overnight until I decided to kill it.

Since then it is no longer recognised by my system.

### Diagnostic

Following these topics [Cannot access disk, partition table broken](https://superuser.com/questions/481196/cannot-access-disk-partition-table-broken) and [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device/241822#241822), I tried this diagnostic, but it looks worse than what the replies indicate.

After rebooting and plugging the hard drive in a different usb port :

```
 $ ls /dev | grep sdb # only finds sdb a few minutes after plugging the HDD in. The rest of the commands are done after this step.
sdb
 $ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

[Welcome message...]

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No such file or directory
 $ lsusb # This does manage to list my Western Digital hard drive
[...]
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1058:10b8 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements Portable (WDBU6Y, WDBUZG)
[...]
 $ sudo ddru_diskutility --inquiry /dev/sdb
ddru_diskutility 1.3 20141005
SCSI inquiry results:
  Vendor ID= WD      
  Product ID= Elements 10B8   
  Product Revision= 1012
  Serial Number= 10B8WXE1
 $ sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.18.0-16-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
 $ sudo smartctl --all -T permissive /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 [...]

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     [No Information Found]
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 24 19:46:05 2019 CET
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
```

I had 3 working partitions on the disk, but they don't show up

Running `ddru_diskutility --inquiry` on `dev/sda` yields an extra paragraph with `ATA identify device results`.

Both TestDisk and PhotoRec don't recognise `/dev/sdb`

### Notes

I only have my laptop with a single SATA plug, no USB stick, and just enough storage to hold the size of the partition I want to recover

Following the advice of [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device/241822#241822), I plan on testing it further by

1. Buying a usb stick, install a live recovery tool on it
2. Replace my computer's SATA SSD with the HDD I want to recover (remove the USB interface)
3. Try to read my SSD in the usb enclosure to see if it is a failure on that end

I will also try to get a new HDD to back up my data on with `ddrescue`, but I was hoping that someone knew a way to make a partition recovery with what I am working with?

#### Partitions present on the HDD (how I remember it)

X : What I don't remember

The partition I want to recover is the one at the end of the HDD (`sdb2`)

```
| # | start (MB) | end (MB) | total size (MB) | following space (MB) |
|---|------------|----------|-----------------|----------------------|
| 1 |     1      |   4097   |       4096      |           0          |
| 3 |    4097    |   8193   |       4096      |           0          |
| 4 |    8193    |  110593  |      102400     |           X          |
| 2 |     X      |    X     |       20480     |           0          |
```

Comment: I once saw a laptop that, in a linux live system, read gigabytes of zeroes from its harddisk with `dd` and later it turned out that this was caused by dust on the sata connector. You might be lucky. So yes. Plug it somewhere else. You are trying the right things.

Comment: Quick answer, maybe someone can elaborate in a real answer: Find out logical block size of HDD if possible (probably 512 bytes). Convert probable start and end of /dev/sdb2 into block numbers (LBA), make it a bit large if necessary. Use `dd` to copy partition to file. If there are read errors, try alternatives to `dd`. Once you recovered most of the data, plug in a new harddisk, store file on that harddisk. Use `hexdump` etc. to see if you can locate the exact start of the partition. Linux can deal with partition in files (loopback device), so mount partition with offset as determined.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out once I get a new HDD.